Add message to ERC-20 token transfer
I am trying to include a message for transparency reasons when performing an ERC-20 token transfer from a safe. I haven't been able to find a way to do this through the transaction builder, or when initiating a token transfer.
I would like to include either a message as a string, or if required an encoded version of the message in the "data" field if that is the correct one, so that the public can see why the payment was made.
Chat support guided me here, hoping I can get some quick assistance on this matter.

How are you building the transaction? Are you using some library like ethers.js or web3.js?


I am trying to include a message for transparency reasons when performing an ERC-20 token transfer from a safe.

ERC-20 does not support additional data for transfer(). You would need to use better, modern, token standards for this.
With ERC-20 you can do this with two transactions approve() and later call a smart contract function makeTransaction(note) which calls ERC20.transferFrom().
However it is very klunky user interaction and it is better just not to use ERC-20 if you can choose a token standard.

Thanks for the details Mikko. I have sorted this issue.
